# из диапазона в последовательность (dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, range

Есть начало и конец диапазона. Помогите вывести список всех последовательностей, если можно, в dataframe

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 00 | 02 |
| 092 | 107 |
| 019 | 109 |

Результат: 00,01,02,092,093,094,095,096,097,098,099,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,019,020,021,022,023,024,025,...,107

Comment: как именно помочь? Поддержать? Давай, ты справишься!

Comment: Тут будет возникать проблема, тк данные указаны в строковом виде, то их придется переводить в числовой, а значит все последовательности будут терять 0, которые идут в начале. Есть ли в этих 0 какая либо необходимость или их можно отбросить?

Answer (score 1):

Вот функция, которая, принимая на вход датафрейм, будет возвращать список элементов, находящихся в диапазоне Start и End. Названия столбцов и датафрйма можете поменять.

```
def var_list(df):
    var_l = []
    for x in range(0, len(df['Start'])):
        l = len(df['End'].iloc()[x]) # узнаем длинну элемента для последующего добавления 0 в начало
        elements = []
        elements = list(range(int(df['Start'].iloc()[x]),int(df['End'].iloc()[x])+1))
        for element in elements:
            el = str(element)
            while len(el) < l:
                el = '0' + el
            var_l.append(el)
    return var_l
```

Comment: Если начало - двузначное число, а конец - четырехзначное, то у вас будет мало нулей. А для заполнения нулем в начале строки уже есть готовая функция zfill()

Comment: Ну я судил по данным из таблицы, там вроде как по длине совпадают значения для каждой строки, если же получится, что длина значения столбца страт меньше чем энд, то тогда будет работать некорректно. Но тут уже претензия к тому, кто вопрос задавал, что не уточнил, будет ли всегда одинаковая длина или нет) @Эникейщик

Comment: В любом случае можно брать длину из end, тк он по идее не может быть меньше длинны start) @Эникейщик

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Start":["00", "092", "019"], "End":["02", "107", "109"]})
```

```
  Start  End
0    00   02
1   092  107
2   019  109
```

```
df["ranges"] = df.apply(lambda x: [f'{n:0{len(x["End"])}}'
                                   for n in range(pd.to_numeric(x["Start"]),
                                                  pd.to_numeric(x["End"]).astype(int)+1)], axis=1)
```

```
    Start   End ranges
0   00  02  [00, 01]
1   092 107 [092, 093, 094, 095, 096, 097, 098, 099, 100, ...
2   019 109 [019, 020, 021, 022, 023, 024, 025, 026, 027, ...
```

Comment: Дополнила код, где конец диапазона тоже входит в последовательность:

Comment: df["ranges"] = df.apply(lambda x: [f'{n:0{len(x["End"])}}'
                                   for n in range(pd.to_numeric(x["Start"]),
                                                  pd.to_numeric(x["End"]).astype(int)+1)], axis=1)

Comment: @AizhanAskhatova да, совершенно верно. Исправил